# Around braid groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, braid-groups

There is a great literature on braid groups, and I wonder whether there are precise references on groups defined in a similar way, but with slight modifications; for example, preventing some strands from switching.

Are there references on such groups?

Comment: What would you like to know?  Such a group is just the preimage in the braid group $B_n$ of a certain subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$, and therefore such a group is a finite-index subgroup of the braid group.

Comment: I am not sure. If we want the product to be well-defined, the subgroup we consider must be included into the pure braid subgroup, ie., in the kernel of the usual morphisme $B_n \to S_n$.

Comment: "prevent from switching" is ambiguous since you seem to have two distinct interpretations of its meaning

Comment: I see, it's more complicated than just the preimage of a subgroup of the symmetric group.  If there's exactly one pair of strands you want to avoid switching (and you're sticking to the pure braid group), then this should be the kernel of the homomorphism $PB_n\to\mathbb{Z}$ that measures the number of times that those two strands have twisted.

Comment: Right, the description is rather ambiguous. What I had in mind is to consider braids where (up to isotopy) some fixed pairs of strands never cross in diagrams. But it is only an example, my question is general: it deals with groups which are defined by families of objects which are more or less braids.